# Using __call in a controller

Tags: controllers, routing, ee-1.14

Is there any examples of using `__call` in a controller to replace a specific action method.

I have a situation where I need to provide different endpoints to the same controller. A reference to each of these end points is available in the database and so instead of hardcoding a method per endpoint I would like every request that hits the controller to be handled by one method.

The only way I have got this to come close to working is by sticking `exit` and other similar undesirable functions within the `__call` method. Surely it's possible to handle the request from here and tell magento not to look for a specific method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, you could extend the `preDispatch` method of your controller, check which actions are allowed and which not (I recommend you against calling `exit`, send a proper HTTP status instead), and redirect the request to a single action in your controller, say `foobarAction`, by using `$this->_forward('foobar')`.

**UPDATE**

I tested my solution, have a look at `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::match`. This calls a method `hasAction` on your controller. If you extend that method in the controller and implement your checks (or simply return `true`, even though I don't recommend it), then you can do what I suggested. Also, since everything happens in `preDispatch`, to prevent the loop you get add something like this:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getActionName() !== 'foobar') {
    $this->_forward('foobar');
}
```

Here for your reference is what I did:

```
class Acme_Module_FoobarController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();
        if ($this->getRequest()->getActionName() !== 'foobar') {
            $this->_forward('foobar');
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function foobarAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setBody('Hey!');
    }

    public function hasAction($action)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. I'm getting a 404 though. I have a function named `testAction` and i call it in `preDispath()` with `$this->_forward('test');`. If I go to a url based on a method that exists in the controller there is no problem so I think the controller is set up correctly,

Comment: I also get an exception if the method exists in the controller `Front controller reached 100 router match iterations`

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tested my answer, but now I did and it does work. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: Still getting a 404 on that. My controller is now extending `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard` and `match()` returns `true`. In my `preDispath()` function I added your code `if ($this->getRequest()->getActionName() !== 'foobar') {
    $this->_forward('foobar');
}`. Fyi `foobar()` exists as `foobarAction()`

Comment: @develophper see my code above, works for me.

Comment: that works, cheers pal.

Answer (score 4):

**[Edit]**
It seams you cannot use `__call` in controllers starting from version CE - 1.8 (and EE 1.13)
it was possible up to 1.7 because of the method `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::hasAction`.
in 1.7 and lower it looked like this:

```
public functionhasAction($action)
{
    return is_callable(array($this, $this->getActionMethodName($action)));
}
```

Starting 1.8 it looks like

```
public functionhasAction($action)
{
    return method_exists(array($this, $this->getActionMethodName($action)));
}
```

This method is called in the standard router when handling the request:

`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::match`

```
...
if (!$controllerInstance->hasAction($action)) {
    continue;
}
...
```

So starting from CE 1.8 the method `somethingAction` really has to exist, not just be callable.

**[Original Answer - works only for versions before CE-1.8]**
yes, you can definitely use `__call` in a controller.
[Check this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22252395/2047249)
but your `__call` will be called for each method that does not exist in the controller.
So you have to make sure that your method called ends with `Action`.
Something like this:

```
public function __call($function, $args){
    if (substr($function, -6) == 'Action') {
         $this->loadLayout('some_default_layout_handle');
         $this->renderLayout();
    }
    else {//otherwise throw an exeption
        throw new Exception ("Method {$function} cannot be called in ". __CLASS__);
    }
}
```

or, if you want to also get the function name you can do this:

```
public function __call($function, $args){
    if (substr($function, -6) == 'Action') {
         $functionName = substr($function, 0, strlen($function) - 6);
         //do something with $functionName
    }
    else {//otherwise throw an exeption
        throw new Exception ("Method {$function} cannot be called in ". __CLASS__);
    }
}
```

so if you call `ROOT/module/controller/something` (and `somethingAction()` does not exist) you end up in the `__call` method.
in the first case you end up with a default page you set, in the second case `$functionName` will be equal with `something`.

Comment: Thanks @marius. I'm trying to get the second option you gave to work by just putting `echo 'this is a test'; exit;` in the if statement but all I'm getting is a 404. Given the controller takes request to other methods I think that part is set up correctly. Are there any other steps you can think of?

Comment: what version of Magento are you using? I want to check if this still works on newer versions. It worked for me in 1.7

Comment: enterprise edition 1.14.2.2

Comment: @develophper. I checked again. It seams you cannot use `__call` starting from ce1.8. I've updated the answer. You will have to go a different direction. Like using a custom router for example.