# Custom module dynamic action controller

Tags: magento-1.9, module, controllers, action

Each controller I need to define how many action can be 
like `saleAction()` , `productAction()` something else.

But I want to make a action who receive all action like `......Action()` It's receive all request except `indexAction()`. Is this possible only edit controller file?

Because now my URL like http://www.example.com/controller/action/parameter
I need to convert that  http://www.example.com/controller/action_as_parameter/somethings_if_need

### UPDATE

Actually I not make yet. But I want to make a simple routers
like

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <marketshop>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Myname_Mymodule</module>
                    <frontName>market</frontName>
                </args>
            </marketshop>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

And controllers also simple. If I can this way then I make my module or find another way

```
class Myname_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction(){
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function globalAction(){
        // I want all action comes here and doing somethings
        // their not have any 404 page
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is something what you might actually need http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/90314/15998

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you will need a custom router.
Add this inside the `global` tag in `config.xml`

```
<events>
    <controller_front_init_routers>
        <observers>
            <market>
                <class>Myname_Mymodule_Controller_Router</class>
                <method>initControllerRouters</method>
            </market>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_routers>
</events>
```

Then create the class `Myname_Mymodule_Controller_Router`.

```
<?php 
class Myname_Mymodule_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract
{
    public function initControllerRouters($observer){
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('market', $this);
        return $this;
    }
    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request){
        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        $pathInfo = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        $params = explode('/', $pathInfo);
        //if module is market and controller is index
        if(isset($params[0]) && $params[0] == 'market' && isset($params[1]) && $params[1] == 'index') {
             //if the action is index - proceed as normal
             if (!isset($params[2]) || $params[2] == 'index') {
                 return false; //standard router will pick it up
             }
             //if action is not index, map the request to the `globalAction`
             if (isset($params[2]) && $params[2] != 'index') {
                 $request->setModuleName('marketshop')  
                     ->setControllerName('index')
                     ->setActionName('global');
                 $request->setAlias(
                     Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                     $pathInfo
                 );
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There some problem default folder name is _controllers_ but U use _controller_ . I change this then it say **Front controller reached 100 router match iterations**. And I want when my first _params_ is market then I use any thing in 2n to last _params_ all are calling my global function.

Comment: It works I have some mistake but I need to change `controller` to `controllers`

Comment: Awesome. If I use `controllers`  It's ok for local but when I upload online then need `controller`. It's I first know today.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can pass a parameter to your main action method and then use a switch to forward to another action of the same controller, for example:

```
public function myAction() {
   $param = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param');

   switch ($param) {
        case 'product':
             $this->_forward('product');
             break;
        case 'sale':
             $this->_forward('sale');
             break;
        /* And so on... */
   }
}

public function saleAction() {
}

public function productAction() {
}
```

But I reckon if you're able to pass a parameter to a main action you can also change the action and access directly the action you need.

Comment: how can I call `myAction()` in my controller ?

Comment: Well it depends on how your module is configured, could you post both your config.xml file and your controller file ?

Comment: Actually I want to make a simple module for this. Just add some code in my question.

Comment: So right now your `indexAction` is called like this www.example.com/market/index/index if you want to call the `myAction` you can call www.example.com/market/index/my

Comment: But I need to convert url `www.example.com/market/index/my` to `www.example.com/market/mymarket` or `www.example.com/market/mymarket/products`  their `mymarket` need to dynamic. If there have any `index` or other parameters that's not feel better.

Answer (score 1):

You can override this method in your controller:

```
public function getActionMethodName($action)
{
    return 'indexAction';
}

public function indexAction()
{
    //action name
    var_dump($this->getRequest()->getActionName());
 }
```

Then always will go to the index action, where you can use the original action name as a parameter.

then:

http://mysite/mymodule/mycontroller/im-dracula-blablabla

Will work!